# jsFunction pass data to backingbean

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a javascript that is calling a function addData(param1,param2,param3,param4) which is calling addClip at the end

And I need to pass those to a backing bean.

```
<a4j:form>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="addClip" action="#{backingBean.goGo}">
        <a4j:actionparam name="param1" assignTo="#{backingBean.param1}"/>
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</a4j:form>
```

But I can't seem to pass any values to the backingbean. I've even tried setting a static value for the actionparam. But when I try to do a Systemout on the setParam1 method it only prints out null. Have I missed anything important?

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: addClip(param1,param2,param3,param4)

Answer (score 0):

Your function defines one parameter, but is called with 4. I assume there is a javascript error (check your JS console (firefox)).

Get rid of the 3 unused parameters, and call it `addClicp(param1)`

Comment: I've added 4 parameters to the JSF code and from the console it seems to print out setting all params but the first. But I can't seem to push values from the javascript to the backingbean. Calling the function goes well but not setting parameters from the JS call.

Comment: how about giving all the code in question, instead of having me guess what's happening? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must do as the following code, if you want to pass 4 parameters to backing bean.

```
<a4j:form>
<a4j:jsFunction name="addClip" action="#{backingBean.goGo}">
    <a4j:actionparam name="param1" assignTo="#{backingBean.param1}"/>
    <a4j:actionparam name="param2" assignTo="#{backingBean.param2}"/>
    <a4j:actionparam name="param3" assignTo="#{backingBean.param3}"/>
    <a4j:actionparam name="param4" assignTo="#{backingBean.param4}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```